# boost logger, multiple logfiles and loggers

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I'm trying to use boost log library in my application but i have problem.

How to configure boost log to have 3 loggers which log to different files.
example:

- main_logger(main.log)
- gui_loger(gui.log)
- some_other_logger(other.log)

I want also use logging on different levels(info, warn, debug, error).

**Example:**

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(main_logger, logging::trivial::debug)
```

How to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multi-file backend: [Boost.Log multi-file backend](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_multifile).